# What is the meaning of Posts.Id and how I look the corresponding post from https://www.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I have downloaded the datadump of Stack Overflow. And I want to retrieve the question from stackoverflow.com by `posts.id` like if the data dump said its id is 305223, then I look for URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223.

But the retrieved posts are not related to my `posts.id` anymore.

How should I retrieve the datadump post from the https://stackoverflow.com/ website?

Comment: id 305223 is Jon Skeet Facts.  It's been deleted; you need 10,000 reputation on Stack Overflow to view it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Amusingly, id 305223 on SO redirects to id 9134 on meta.

Comment: Why was that question marked as "spam or offensive?"  EDIT: Probably because that was the only means of flagging/closure in 2009.

Comment: Guess we really do hate [tag:fun]

Comment: @JAL Can we introduce fun here?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. The id found in the Posts.xml belongs to the question (or answer) id found in the url of your browser.

You don't even have to worry about if the id of the post belongs to an answer or a question.

Visiting [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112320`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112320) nicely highlights the answer.

The problem you're facing is the deletion of posts. Due to community moderation, Roomba scripts, moderators or staff posts get deleted. Those posts are however soft-deleted, meaning that with enough reputation (10K on Stack Overflow) you can see deleted posts if you know the url. The post with your id looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Capiz.png).